# CS1929 - Trying to read a file, and skip to the line that contains a certain string and return that line's content

Tags: c#

The error occurs in the SkipWhile method, in the second "line" keyword. Displays the following log

CS1929 "char" does not contain a definition for "Contains" and the best extension method overload "Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, string)" requires a receiver of type "IQueryable"

```
    public static void loginEmployee(string user, string password)
    {
        string filename = "servidores_cadastrados_db_backup.txt";
        string path = AppConfig.appconfig.defaultPath;
        path = Path.Combine(path, filename);

        if (File.ReadAllText(path).Contains(user))
        {

            employee.Registration = File.ReadAllText(path).SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(user))
            .TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains(user));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid User or Password..", "Invalid Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ReadAllText returns 1 string, not a list of lines

Comment: `ReadAllText` gives you the entire contents of the file as a single string. If you're wanting to work with lines, I'd probably recommend you consider switching to `ReadAllLines` instead. Also, instead of reading the entire content of the file twice, probably jump straight to your `SkipWhile`/`TakeWhile` code and then detect if that returned no lines.

Comment: Sounds like a very insecure way of testing for security - if the input text contains a username FOOBAR and a username tested is FOO or BAR, both will be found when testing for user. I'm aware that's not your question though.

Comment: It's not really safe, but it's just a prototype. Thanks for the remark. I'll take one more look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `File.ReadAllText` and then using `SkipWhile` on that which will return each character of the text. What you should be using is `File.ReadLines` and iterating over the lines.

```
employee.Registration = File.ReadLines(path).SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(user))
        .TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains(user));
```

Also, I think your `.TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains(user)` is wrong, shouldn't it be trying to match on the `user` instead of not match?

```
employee.Registration = File.ReadLines(path).SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(user))
        .TakeWhile(line => line.Contains(user));
```

Comment: Hey. It wasn't exactly the right answer but it set me on the path to the right answer. Thanks. Also, the ".TakeWhile()" was actually wrong.